# How to load classes in php

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload

I need to understand how to load classes in php. I want to access classes methods by instantiate the class only with its name, for example:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->method();
```

And not like this:

```
$foo = new \Class\Bar\Foo();
```

I'm in a Symfony 2.7 environment.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
My bad, I should have specified that I'd like to use classes like this in the whole project, not only in a few files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `use` those classes (i.e. import them) like:

```
use strrife\MyBundle\Entity as Entity;

...

$e = new Entity();
```

The official docs can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php).

#### PS

If you're using some IDE (for example, PHPStorm which personally I highly recommend), then, when you type `Entity` and this class wasn't imported yet, it gives you a list of options to import that class from.

#### EDIT

You shouldn't do that.

Importing the classes like that in the entire project is actually a bad idea because that might cause naming conflicts (and probably will if you'd like to do that for Symfony classes).

As a workaround for your project classes you can add a few lines to `composer.json` specifying the autoload paths to all your project folders.

You can also:

- put all your entities to one single folder (very bad)
- or write a custom `__autoload()` function that would iterate through files and folders searching for your class ([docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)), but it'd bring the same problems + some performance issues.

But I highly discourage you from doing that because... well, namespaces bring order and structure and you're likely to end up with class redeclarations.

Comment: Thanks Alexander that clarifies a bit. I edited my question, I wasn't specific enough, I'm sorry